# MacBook's Switchable Graphics to toggle by script

Tags: macos, applescript

Recently I had a problem with Photoshop CS4 but I solved the problem by turning off switchable graphics in System Preferences.

Is there any way to toggle switchable graphics with a program?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEylS.png "Screenshot"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool for this is Cody Krieger's [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io), which not only allows forcing the setting from the menu bar, but also does a fine job of monitoring why your system has switched GPU modes.